# Push Notification does not take the user to that particular screen from which it has got chat message?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I want to make a hybrid app in ionic, in which we successfully achieve to get the push notification in its android part. But that push notification does not take the user to the particular screen from which it got message. It takes the user to the contact list

Comment: contact list is the app home?

Answer (score 0):

Add custom data when sending a push notification [as shown here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push#section-adding-custom-data-to-your-notifications).

And then in `onNotification` handler, check for payload and use the custom data to go to a route.

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
  "onNotification": function (notification) {
    var payload = notification.payload;
    console.log(notification, payload);
    //alert(notification);
  }
});
```

Your custom data can contain, may be a state name or key which you can use to uniquely route to particular state.